# Android ImageButton image comparison

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have this little code here:

MainActivity.java:

```
public void Images(View v)
{
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) v;
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_pressed_button);
}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
            android:src="@drawable/c4_button" 
            android:onClick="Images"/>
```

All I want to do is to compare two images ('drawables'?) from the ImageButton, just like that:

```
public void Images(View v)
{
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) v;
    if(xxxx == R.drawable.c4_pressed_button)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_button);
    else i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_pressed_button);
}
```

And I don't know what I have to put in xxxx to make that comparison.
I know R.drawable.c4_pressed_button is an Int, but I don't know how to get the ImageButton image to compare it to that. Any help?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish by comparing the images?

Comment: I want to change the ImageButton image from one to other if is different than the one is stated. It is in the third code frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTag()` and `getTag()` method

```
public void Images(View v)
{
ImageButton i = (ImageButton) v;
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_pressed_button);
i.setTag("R.drawable.c4_pressed_button");
}
```

And then do comparison

```
public void Images(View v)
{
ImageButton i = (ImageButton) v;
String imageName = (String) i.getTag();
if(imageName.equals("R.drawable.c4_pressed_button"))
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_button);
else i.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4_pressed_button);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! But does not exist a method to get the image? Do I have to do it with tags ?